# DataTables plugin for javascript works only on jQuery 1.12.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

in section of compatibility of DataTables website (https://datatables.net/download/compatibility)
is written

"DataTables and its extensions all require jQuery 1.7 or newer. Like all software, it is recommended that you always use the latest version of jQuery that is available as it will include additional features, performance enhancements and bug fixes"

so I decided to test his "zero configuration" example in my project with last version of jquery (jquery-3.1.1.min.js) but doesn't work.

Last version of jQuery 
https://jsfiddle.net/7LpaLqyL/ nothing is working

Version 1.12.4 of jQuery (version in the example)
https://jsfiddle.net/zr7coz5u/ is working

and the code is the same
`$('#example').DataTable();`

so my question is, how can I do to use last version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has invalid loading order, jQuery DataTables must be loaded **after** jQuery.

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">     

<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/7LpaLqyL/1/) for code and demonstration.